# How to implicitly use the base definition of a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, abc, abstract-base-class

I'm currently developping for python 2, and I'm trying to use abstract base classes to simulate interfaces. I have an interface, a base implementation of that interface and many subclasses that extend the base implementation. It looks like this:

```
class Interface(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

class IAudit(Interface):
    @abstractproperty
    def timestamp(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractproperty
    def audit_type(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class BaseAudit(IAudit):
    def __init__(self, audit_type):
        # init logic
        pass

    @property
    def timestamp(self):
        return self._timestamp

    @property
    def audit_type(self):
        return self._audit_type

class ConcreteAudit(BaseAudit):
    def __init__(self, audit_type):
        # init logic
        super(ConcreteAudit, self).__init__(audit_type)
        pass
```

However PyCharm notifies me that `ConcreteAudit` should implement all abstract methods. However, `BaseAudit` (which is not specified as an abc) already implements those methods, and ­­­­`ConcreteAudit` is a subclass of `BaseAudit`. Why is PyCharm warning me? Shouldn't it detect that `IAudit`'s contract is already implemented through `BaseAudit`?

Answer (score 2):

Why is PyCharm warning you?

Because *all* Python IDEs suck, that's why.

Whenever an intern/junior programmer/peer tells me that something that I wrote isn't working for him, I tell him that I'm not discussing it until he tries it by executing a Python script from the command line or from the stock interpreter.  99% of the time, the problem disappears.

Why do they suck?  Beats me.  But they all sometimes hide exceptions, sometimes make it possible to have stuff imported you didn't know about, and all sometimes decide (as in this case) that something is problematic that a real program running on the stock interpreter simply won't have a problem with.

I tried you code in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, and as long as I add `from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty` at the top, it runs peachy-keen fine.

So just ditch PyCharm, or update the tags to show that's where the error is.